# React router how to display each component on click on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple menu created in React that has four links. When I click each link a different component should be rendered below the menu. currently my router displays each component on a new page, how can I show them using the React Router on the same page on click? I tried using `Switch` and moving the `BrowserRouter` but it did not work. Here is the menu component:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


class BlogCategoriesMenu extends Component {


  render() {
    return(
        <div className="blog-categories-menu">
        <div className="blog-categories-menu__items">
         <NavLink to="/planets" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a"  activeClassName="isActive">Planets</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/signs" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Signs</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/planetary-aspects"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Planetary Aspects</NavLink>
         <NavLink to="/houses"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Houses</NavLink>
         <div className="content-container">
         </div>
         </div>
       </div>

    )
  }
} 

export default BlogCategoriesMenu;
```

and here are the routes that I have set in my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home/Home.jsx'
import Error from './components/Error/Error.jsx';
import Blog from './components//Blog//Blog.jsx';
import Post from './components/Post/Post.jsx';
import Planets from './components/Planets/Planets.jsx';
import Signs from './components//Signs/Signs.jsx';
import PlanetaryAspects from './components/PlanetaryAspects/PlanetaryAspects.jsx';
import Houses from './components/Houses/Houses.jsx';

const App = () => {

  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
   <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} exact/>
   <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} exact/>
   <Route path="/planets" component={Planets}></Route>
   <Route path="/signs" component={Signs}></Route>
   <Route path="/planetary-aspects" component={PlanetaryAspects}></Route>
   <Route path="/houses" component={Houses}></Route>
   <Route component={Error}/>
   </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```displays each component on a new page``` ? Is it that it doesn't show the menu above your component ?

Comment: yes. when you click on the menu link the component shows in a new page, it does not get rendered under the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your routes inside the `BlogCategoriesMenu` component.

Edit your `BlogCategoriesMenu` to make it accept child components

```
class BlogCategoriesMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
         //...
         <div className="content-container">
            {this.props.children /*Add this line*/}
         </div>
         //...
    );
  }
} 

export default BlogCategoriesMenu;
```

Then in `App.js`

```
const App = () => {

  return (
   <BlogCategoriesMenu>
     <BrowserRouter>
       {/*...*/}
     </BrowserRouter>
   </BlogCategoriesMenu>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your component to be rendered below the menu, there's to possibilities :

1. put your menu component and your component in a Page component :

```
// the route
<Route path="/planets" component={PlanetsPage}></Route>

// the Page
export default PlanetsPage = () => (
  <>
    <BlogCategoriesMenu/>
    <Planets/>
  </>
)
```

2. Lower your `Routes` under the menu :

```
// route
<Route path="/astronomy" component={Astronomy}/>

// wrapper component
export default Astronomy = () => (
  <>
    <BlogCategoriesMenu/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/planets" component={Planets}></Route>
      <Route path="/signs" component={Signs}></Route>
      <Route path="/planetary-aspects" component={PlanetaryAspects}></Route>
      <Route path="/houses" component={Houses}></Route>
      <Route component={Error}/>
    </Switch>
  </>
)

// new NavLinks
<NavLink to="/astronomy/planets" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a"  activeClassName="isActive">Planets</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/astronomy/signs" className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Signs</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/astronomy/planetary-aspects"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Planetary Aspects</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/astronomy/houses"  className="blog-categories-menu__items-a" activeClassName="isActive">Houses</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is outside `<Switch>` component will be rendered with routed components. So add `<BlogCategoriesMenu />` to `App` component, like this

```
const App = () => {

  return (
   <BrowserRouter>

   <BlogCategoriesMenu />

   <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
   <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} exact/>
   <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} exact/>
   <Route path="/planets" component={Planets}></Route>
   <Route path="/signs" component={Signs}></Route>
   <Route path="/planetary-aspects" component={PlanetaryAspects}></Route>
   <Route path="/houses" component={Houses}></Route>
   <Route component={Error}/>
   </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Make sure to put component holding `<NavLink>` inside `<BrowserRouter>`. Otherwise it will not render.

Here is small [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/routermenu-8odjj)